# Group data based on specific conditions and find duration in R or Python

Tags: python, r, dplyr, tidyverse

**I have a dataset, df, that looks like the following:**

```
 subject    recipient                  length   folder    message  date                       edit
                                        80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:01 AM        T                                    
                                        80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:05 AM        T                   
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:10 AM        T
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:15 AM        T
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80      out                1/2/2020 1:00:30 AM        T
some       k                           900      in       jjjjj     1/2/2020 1:00:35 AM        F
some       k                           900      in       jjjjj     1/2/2020 1:00:36 AM        F 
some       k                           900      in       jjjjj     1/2/2020 1:00:37 AM        F
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80    draft                1/2/2020 1:02:00 AM        T
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com    80    draft                1/2/2020 1:02:05 AM        T    
no         a                          900       in        iii      1/2/2020 1:02:10 AM        F
no         a                          900       in        iii      1/2/2020 1:02:15 AM        F
no         a                          900       in        iii      1/2/2020 1:02:20 AM        F
no         a                          900       in        iii      1/2/2020 1:02:25 AM        F
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com   80    draft                 1/2/2020 1:03:00 AM        T
hey        sarah@mail.com,g@mail.com   80    draft                 1/2/2020 1:03:20 AM        T
```

**Background and Ojective**

The dataset represents when a user is editing a message, steps away, and resumes to that same exact message. I am trying to capture the total duration of the message at hand. I know that I must first group the message. I wish to group the message based on these conditions:

If the Folder column is == "out" OR "draft", if the Message column is == "", and if the Edit == "T", the Length column should also be consecutively identical. So once I have these groups, I wish to find the duration (start and end) of these groups. For example the first group duration would be 29 seconds, because it starts at 1/2/2020 1:00:01 AM and ends at 1/2/2020 1:00:30 AM. The second group would start at 1/2/2020 1:02:00 and ends at 1:02:05 AM. Lastly the third group starts at 1/2/2020 1:03:00 AM and ends at 1:03:20 AM. Furthermore, since these groups all belong to the SAME message, I'd like to link these altogether by using the logic if: The Subject, Recipient, and Length contents in the last row of a group match the first row of the next groups Subject, Recipient and Length, then these all belong to the same group.

I'd like the output to look like this:

**Desired Output**

```
 Start                  End                        Duration          Group  Subject  Length
 1/2/2020 1:00:10 AM    1/2/2020 1:00:30 AM        20                A      hey       80
 1/2/2020 1:02:00 AM    1/2/2020 1:02:05 AM        5                 A      hey       80
 1/2/2020 1:03:10 AM    1/2/2020 1:03:20 AM        20                A      hey       80
```

Here is my dput

```
  structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
  4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
 "hey", "no", "some"), class = "factor"), Recipient = structure(c(1L, 
 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
 2L), .Label = c("", " ", "a", "k", "sarah@mail.com,gee@mail.com"
  ), class = "factor"), Length = c(80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 900L, 
 900L, 900L, 80L, 80L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 80L, 80L, NA, NA
 ), Folder = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "draft", "in", 
 "out"), class = "factor"), Message = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
 "jjjjjjj", "llll"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(2L, 
 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "1/2/2020 1:00:01 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:05 AM", 
"1/2/2020 1:00:10 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:15 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:30 AM", 
"1/2/2020 1:00:35 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:36 AM", "1/2/2020 1:00:37 AM", 
"1/2/2020 1:02:00 AM", "1/2/2020 1:02:05 AM", "1/2/2020 1:02:10 AM", 
"1/2/2020 1:02:15 AM", "1/2/2020 1:02:20 AM", "1/2/2020 1:02:25 AM", 
"1/2/2020 1:03:00 AM", "1/2/2020 1:03:20 AM"), class = "factor"), 
Edit = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

**This is what I am working on:**

```
   df <- df %>% 
    mutate(Message = ifelse(is.na(Message), '', Message)) %>% 
    mutate(
    cond = Edit & Folder %in% c('out', 'draft') & Message == ''
       ) %>% 
    mutate(grp = cumsum(!cond)) %>% 
   filter(cond, Subject = '')

   df$Date <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df$Date), format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS')

   get_group_number = function(){
   i = 0
   function(){
   i <<- i+1
     i
       }
   }
  group_number = get_group_number()
  df <- df %>% group_by(Subject, Recipient, Length) %>% mutate(Group = group_number())

  df %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(Start = min(Date), End = max(Date),
         Duration = End - Start, Group = unique(Group)[1])
```

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>% 
  # The original data was loaded as factors, which have their uses, but
  #   converting those to characters will be simpler to work with here.
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  # I'm replacing NA in Subj & Recip with an empty string, and trimming 
  #    excess spaces from the start and end. One of the recipients is " "
  #    but I assume that's functionally the same as blank.
  mutate_at(c("Subject", "Recipient"), ~if_else(is.na(.), "", stringr::str_trim(.))) %>%
  filter(Subject != '') %>%
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS')) %>%
  mutate(cond = Edit & Folder %in% c('out', 'draft') & Message == '') %>% 
  mutate(segment = cumsum(!cond)) %>%
  filter(cond) %>%   # EDIT: Added to exclude rows matching cond

  # Get summary stats for each segment
  group_by(Subject, Recipient, Length, segment) %>%
  summarize(Start = min(Date),
            End = max(Date),
            Duration = End - Start) %>%

  # This counts the number of times that these columns don't match their
  #   predecessor. TRUE = 1, so we get 1 when anything changes.
  #   Look at ?lag for more on what those parameters mean.
  mutate(new_group = (Subject   != lag(Subject, 1, "")) *
                     (Recipient != lag(Recipient, 1, "")) *
                     (Length    != lag(Length, 1, ""))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(group = LETTERS[cumsum(new_group)])



# A tibble: 3 x 9
  Subject Recipient                   Length segment Start               End                 Duration new_group group
  <chr>   <chr>                        <int>   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>       <int> <chr>
1 hey     sarah@mail.com,gee@mail.com     80       0 2020-01-02 01:00:10 2020-01-02 01:00:30 20 secs          1 A    
2 hey     sarah@mail.com,gee@mail.com     80       3 2020-01-02 01:02:00 2020-01-02 01:02:05  5 secs          0 A    
3 hey     sarah@mail.com,gee@mail.com     80       7 2020-01-02 01:03:00 2020-01-02 01:03:20 20 secs          0 A
```

Comment: Thank you for your time @jon I will try this now. I wish to exclude all the entries that are not edit = T, Message == "" and Folder is == out or draft. I was thinking that all the subjects with 'no' and 'some' must be excluded since they do not meet conditions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I'm following. If edit is not TRUE, exclude. If Message is blank, exclude. If folder isn't out or draft, exclude. Is that right?

Comment: yes that's correct @jon , also I wish to keep the subject if its blank (if possible)

Comment: Does it need to fit one or all of those conditions to exclude?

Comment: yes @Jon - Exclude if Edit is not true, if the folder is not out or draft and if the message is not blank I am wanting to exclude these

Comment: Thankyou @jon this works- I may add, how do I KEEP the rows with empty subject? (is it possible not to filter it out?) -I suppose I can just remove that line? filter(Subject != '') %>%

Comment: I am trying to learn @jon so this line :  mutate(cond = Edit & Folder %in% c('out', 'draft') & Message == '')     is saying the conditions right ? Where does it specify to remove if the Edit is not T?? I am still learning thank you

Comment: It makes a new column called `cond`. It will be `TRUE` if all three conditions are `TRUE`: 1) Is `Edit` `TRUE`? 2) Is the value of `Folder` found in the vector `c('out', 'draft')` i.e. does it match one of those?  3) Is the message an empty character string?

Comment: Hi- @Jon Spring   ,thank you! furthermore to INCLUDE the blank subject values, and start the count at:  1/2/2020 1:00:01 AM    ,    would I just exclude this line? filter(Subject != '') %>% ?? I tried to do this but get an error: Error: Column `group` must be length 4 (the number of rows) or one, not 3...Do I have to change something else within the code??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208730/discussion-between-jon-spring-and-tanisha-hudson).

Comment: ok @Jon I opened the chat, I hope you can see it there? Thank you!